# No error and no row is added to the database table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv, pymysql

I am trying to add rows from a csv file called 'items.csv' to a table named 'articles2' in a mysql database named  'city_details '. The python script didn't produce any warning or error. Also no row was inserted in the database. Here's the code:

```
    import csv
    import re
    import pymysql
    import sys

    connection = pymysql.connect (host = "localhost", user = "root", passwd = ".....", db = "city_details")       
    cursor = connection.cursor ()

    def insert_articles2(rows):
      for row in rows:
        sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO articles2 (country, event_name, md5, date_added, profile_image, banner, sDate, eDate, address_line1, address_line2, pincode, state, city, locality, full_address, latitude, longitude, start_time, end_time, description, website, fb_page, fb_event_page, event_hashtag, source_name, source_url, email_id_organizer, ticket_url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" 
        cursor.execute = (sql, (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27]))

    rows = csv.reader(open("items.csv", "r"))
    insert_articles2(rows)

connection.commit()
```

I have provided the structure of 'Create table' command which created the table:

```
Table structure for table `articles2`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles2` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `md5` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_image` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `banner` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `sDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `eDate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `address_line1` mediumtext,
  `address_line2` mediumtext,
  `pincode` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `city` text NOT NULL,
  `locality` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `full_address` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext CHARACTER SET utf16 NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_page` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fb_event_page` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_hashtag` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `source_url` varchar(350) NOT NULL,
  `email_id_organizer` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ticket_url` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `full_address` (`full_address`),
  KEY `full_address_2` (`full_address`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `event_name` (`event_name`),
  KEY `sDate` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate` (`eDate`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`),
  KEY `country` (`country`),
  KEY `event_name_2` (`event_name`),
  KEY `sDate_2` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate_2` (`eDate`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `locality` (`locality`),
  KEY `start_time` (`start_time`),
  KEY `start_time_2` (`start_time`),
  KEY `end_time` (`end_time`),
  KEY `id_3` (`id`),
  KEY `id_4` (`id`),
  KEY `event_name_3` (`event_name`),
  KEY `md5` (`md5`),
  KEY `sDate_3` (`sDate`),
  KEY `eDate_3` (`eDate`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
  KEY `start_time_3` (`start_time`),
  KEY `end_time_2` (`end_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4182 ;
```

Comment: I think you should boil it down a little. Try to figure out the minimum code required for it to fail. It'll probably help you to get the answer you want :)

Comment: There are plenty of places this could have failed, but I guess it will be because you didn't commit the transaction.

Comment: As @DanielRoseman states you should  make a commit to tell the db to store the changes made in the transaction. `connection.commit()`

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I committed it now. Still nothing added to the db.

Comment: @iregular : I made the change. Nothing changed. What else can possibly hinder the rows to be added to the db?

Comment: @DanielRoseman : I committed the db. Nothing changed. What else can possibly hinder the rows to be added to the db?

Comment: Hard to tell I don't know how you crafted your database.
However I suspect it could be the `Ignore` keyword which won't insert rows it it results in a duplicate key. However it should generate an warning. 
It would be easier if we could actually see how you crafted your db and what is being sent

Comment: @iregular : I have provided the format of 'crate table ' command. Tell me what more you want to see.

Comment: Your create script seem correct (without me actually having tested it). Can I have a sample of what you are trying to insert i.e. an insert statement for inserting a row into the db?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168511/discussion-between-deba-and-i-regular).